# SQLite bind insert statement throwing error with unique key

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using the following code to do an insert into the database using a batch insert for android SQLite

```
                  String sql = "INSERT INTO "+ SQL_DATABASE_GLOBALS.TEMPSORT_TABLE +" VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
                  Log.d("Line", "1");
               SQLiteStatement statement = SQL_DATABASE_GLOBALS.SQL_DATABASE.compileStatement(sql);
              Log.d("Line", "2");

              SQL_DATABASE_GLOBALS.SQL_DATABASE.beginTransaction();
              Log.d("Line", "3");

                        statement.clearBindings();
                        statement.bindLong(1, 0);
                        statement.bindString(2, "Site");
                        statement.bindString(3, this.SearchLocation);
                        statement.bindString(4, TitleElement);
                        statement.bindString(5, NewURL);
                        statement.bindString(6, ImageHREFElement);
                        statement.bindString(7, PriceElement);
                        statement.bindString(8, "WebSIteDescription"); //Description
                        statement.bindString(9, LocationElement);
                        statement.bindString(10, TrueDateTime);
                        statement.bindString(11, TrueDateTime);
                        Log.d("Line", "4");

                       long result = statement.executeInsert();
                       Log.d("Results", "SQL Result" + result);
             SQL_DATABASE_GLOBALS.SQL_DATABASE.setTransactionSuccessful();  
              SQL_DATABASE_GLOBALS.SQL_DATABASE.endTransaction();
```

Now the insert itself works works but the problem i'm having is the 1st item in the database is actually a unique auto increment column. So i'm getting the error...

"Primary Key must be Unique"

How would I deal with this normally? do i really have to sit and create the actual insert statement itself fully instead of just using the the method I did?

No I don't want to use constructed values either, i'm wanting to stick with this type of insert.

Comment: btw, you should do yourself a favour and address the columns explicitly, not implicitly. Means : INSERT INTO Foo(a,b) VALUES (?,?). Otherwise you will run into trouble sooner or later ... when your app lives and gets the first modifications.

Answer (score 1):

You're binding the value 0 to the unique column. To make the autoincrement mechanism kick in, bind a null there.

Change

```
statement.bindLong(1, 0);
```

to

```
statement.bindNull(1);
```